# ORACLE FOOR LOOP with Cursor

Tags: oracle, for-loop, cursor, fetch

I have LOOP statement with Cursor and fetch and that works but I wanna "FOR LOOP".

```
DECLARE
   emp_rec employees%ROWTYPE;
   CURSOR Cur_emp IS 
     SELECT * 
       FROM employees 
      order by employees.last_name asc; 
BEGIN
   OPEN Cur_emp;
   LOOP
      FETCH Cur_emp INTO emp_rec; 
      exit when Cur_emp%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(‘Employee Name–>’|| emp_rec.LAST_NAME);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE Cur_emp;  
END;
```

I wanna like:

```
DECLARE
   emp_rec employees%ROWTYPE;
   CURSOR Cur_emp IS 
     SELECT * 
       FROM employees 
      order by employees.last_name asc; 
BEGIN
   FOR item IN Cur_emp
   LOOP
     FETCH Cur_emp INTO emp_rec;
     exit when Cur_emp%notfound;
     dbms_output.put_line(‘Employee Name–>’|| emp_rec.LAST_NAME);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This does not works because of `FETCH Cur_emp INTO emp_rec INVALID CURSOR ORA-01001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `FETCH` and `EXIT WHEN`, and replace emp_rec reference with item, like this:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR Cur_emp IS SELECT * FROM employees order by employees.last_name asc; 
BEGIN
FOR item IN Cur_emp
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(‘Employee Name–>’|| item.LAST_NAME);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I know that it would work. I find answer in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i45320

Comment: Thank you but you ask not my question. Anyway I give you plus